# How to compare a property value in multiple objects of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

How can I compare a property value in multiple objects of an array? 
I have a few objects in array `x`.

```
var arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}, ...]
```

I want to compare and return true if the value of `'a'` is same in all the objects in the array

Comment: Use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), `array.every(el => el.a === 1)`.

Comment: So, what's the problem? This seems pretty trivial to do, what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: I actually want to return true if the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: @VLAZ there's no need to be unsupportive. I think that the question is very clear.

Comment: @Rpx at the time I had left the comment, the question was *different*. It asked to check if `a` is `1` in the entire array. It was later clarified that OP wants to check if `a` is *the same* regardless of what the value is.

Comment: right, I still think that sometimes people just have too much to explain and it is hard to put all in written so there are supportive ways to ask for people to improve their questions. Otherwise they will be put off by the lack of support and their skills are not going to improve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For checking if all objects contains for the same key the same value, you could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting the first item and check against the actual item.

```js
var array = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 1, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 }],
    key = 'a';

console.log(array.every((a, _, [b]) => a[key] === b[key]));
```

Taking a substring for compairing

```js
var array = [{ a: 12345, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 12367, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 }];

console.log(array.every((a, _, [b]) => a.a.toString().slice(0, 3) === b.a.toString().slice(0, 3)));
```

ES5

```js
var array = [{ a: 12345, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 12367, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 }];

console.log(array.every(function (a, _, b) {
    return a.a.toString().slice(0, 3) === b[0].a.toString().slice(0, 3);
}));
```

Comment: I actually want to return true if the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: Thanks much! This is working. How can I check the if the first three characters of 'a' are same and return true?
say if the array is like this
var array = [{ a: 12345, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 12367, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 }]

Comment: which characters do you mean?

Comment: var array = [{ a: 12345, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 12367, x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 }]

This has a: 12345 and a: 12367 since first three numbers are same (i.e. 123) it should return true.

Comment: This is perfect but can you please do this in ES5?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const data1 = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}];
const data2 = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}, {a: 2}];

data1.reduce((acc, item) => acc && item.a === 1, true); // true
data2.reduce((acc, item) => acc && item.a === 1, true); // false
```

---

For getting `true` if the value of `a` is same in all objects in the array I would use `Array.prototype.some` with simple inversion:

```
!data1.some((item, index, list) => item.a !== list[index && 1 - 1].a); // true
!data2.some((item, index, list) => item.a !== list[index && 1 - 1].a); // false
```

Here I'm looking for the first item in the list which has `a` property that does not match `a` property of the previous item. Zero-indexed item will be skipped, it will be compared with itself (`index && 1 - 1` is just `0` if index is `0`). The result is being inverted with `!`, so I will have `true` if no item is found.

Comment: I actually want to return true if the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: @ChrisJake I updated the answer to satisfy your second requirement with `some` approach

Answer (score 2):

I would simple use `Array.prototype.every()` to test if all the objects have `a` as `1`.

```js
var arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}];
let result = arr.every((obj)=> obj.a === 1);
console.log(result);//true

arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}, {a:2, x:2, y:3, z:4}];
result = arr.every((obj)=> obj.a === 1);
console.log(result);//false

//Checks whether all the a keys is same in the array of objects.
result = arr.every((obj)=> obj.a === arr[0].a);
console.log(result); //false

arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}];
result = arr.every((obj)=> obj.a === arr[0].a);
console.log(result); //true
```

Comment: I actually want to return true if the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: You would get a boolean from the `Array.prototype.every()` which you can return.

Comment: Value of 'a' can be anything not exactly '1'. I want to return true after checking the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: You can try this: `arr.every(obj => obj.a === arr[0].a);` here I am checking the value of the first `a` and comparing that with the rest of the objects. If any of the a values are different it would return `false`. If all `a` values are same then it must match with the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for this.

It allows you to run a test function over each element in an array and return true if every element in the array passes, and return false otherwise.

EDIT: If you wanted to check that all objects have property `a` and all values are equal you could do the following:

```
const x = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {a:1, x:2, y:3, z:4}, {a:2, g:33, f:100}];
let condition = x.every( elem => elem.a == x[0].a);
```

You can also use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to return true or false if ***any one*** of the elements passes the test.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft2x5vrs/7/) that shows the case

Comment: I actually want to return true if the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: Value of 'a' can be anything not exactly '1'. I want to return true after checking the value of 'a' is same in all objects in the array

Comment: You could set the value of the first object's a attribute to a variable and use every as above to check against the variable

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that change.